# CSS Issue Overlapping Image

Tags: html, css

Please see the attached image,I want to design this in html,Quite successful.But when I test it on different resolutions the red box moves here and there.I made the design in 100% width and height 100%

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">

    #green-box { width: 75%; background: green; float: left; position: relative; height: 100%; overflow: visible; position: relative; }
    #blue-box { width: 25%; background: blue; float: left; height: 100%; }
    #red-box {
        position: relative;
        top: 50px;
        left:450px;
        width: 357px;
        background: red;
        height: 207px;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
    #green-box-content
    {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1600px;
        height:800px;


    }
</style>
<div id="container">

        <div id="green-box">
        <div id="green-box-content">
            <p>Here is some text!</p>
            <div id="red-box"></div>
        </div> 
        </div>

        <div id="blue-box">

        </div>

        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is in how you are trying to position the element.  It looks like you want it to be centered between the blue and green, but you're positioning from the left-hand side.  Once the width of the green changes, it won't be where you want it.  It would be better to position from the right (the border between the two) and set `right` to -1/2 of the width.

Also, 100% height will only work if the parent containers have a set height

Here's the modified CSS, and a [fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/pJ3Kz/)

```
#blue-box,
#green-box {
    height: 300px;
}

#green-box { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 75%; 
    float: left; 

    background: green; 
}
#blue-box { 
    width: 25%; 
    float: left;

    background: blue; 
}
#red-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: -178px; /* width / 2 */

    width: 357px;
    height: 207px;

    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Best,Thanks.Thats the thing i am missing

Comment: But if i extend the height of blue and green box to 100%,the red box disappears

Comment: I would need to know the rest of the code around it to help, since setting the height to 100% depends on the parent elements also having a height declared.  It would also be helpful to know which browser you're looking at this in.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width` and `height` from `#green-box-content`, works perfectly in my local.

```
 #green-box-content
    {
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

check this [image: screenshot] after making the change in my local.

Comment: try zoom in/Zoom out box will definitely move

Answer (score -1):

I think you should Percentage of the red box as you have used it for green and blue and position as absolute.

http://jsfiddle.net/ccEKk/

if I am wrong update the fiddle so that someone can help you with it

```
 #red-box {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5%;
        left:45%;
        width: 35%;
        background: red;
        height: 20%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```